# midasR forecast produces NA value

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

I want a forecast 1-step with Midas Package, but when i try to do the result are NA. The code are the next.

```
model1=midas_r(TC ~
           mls(TC, 1, 1)+
           mls(EMCI_MXN, 2:5, 4, nealmon) , 
          data=list(dlog_men,
                    EMCI_MXN=dlog_dS$EMCI_MXN),
          start = list(EMCI_MXN=rep(0,3)))
model2=midas_r(TC ~
         mls(TC, 1, 1)+
         mls(EMCI_MXN, 2:5, 4, lcauchyp) , 
       data=list(dlog_men,
                 EMCI_MXN=dlog_dS$EMCI_MXN),
       start = list(EMCI_MXN=c(1,1,1)))

model_frcst=midasr::forecast(model2, newdata=list( 
EMCI_MXN =c(-.02,rep(NA,3)) #Adding new value
),method="dynamic")
```

I´ve tried this, but the result is the same:

```
average_forecast(list(model1, model2),data=list( 
TC=c(dlog_men$TC, NA),
EMCI_MXN =c(dlog_dS$EMCI_MXN,rep(NA,4))
), insample= 1:146, outsample = 147
)
```

Thank´s a lot.